# What is the jQuery selector for selecting anchor elements with a particular class in a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, selector

I have some code like this and I want to select every `<a>` tag with the class `status` in the div `foo`

```
<div id="foo">
...
<a class = "status"> ... </a>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot a closing quote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this `$('#foo').find('.status')`

Comment: hasClass returns boolean, not the elements that actually has the class. Anyway, the link is great.

Answer (score 4):

The selector would be:

```
$("#foo a.status");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

```
$("#foo a.status")
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
$("#foo").find("a.status")
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$('div#foo > a.status')
```

it selects the anchors which are DIRECT children of div #foo

Comment: A note: This will select only the anchors with a class of `status` that are *direct children* of the div with an id of `foo`. This may be what the OP was after, I just wanted to provide clarity here.

Comment: @Alex thanx, I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div#foo a.status')
```

The docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#foo')     //select elm with id foo
.find('a.status')  //find anchor with class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "jQuery selector", what you mean is  :

**either *CSS selector*** :

In that case the answer is `div#foo a.status` or also `div#foo > a.status` (depending if there are intermediate containers)

**or *jQuery functions*** :

In that case there are several ways to do it :

- `$('div#foo a.status')`
- `$('div#foo > a.status')`
- `$('div#foo').find('a.status')`
- `$('div#foo').children('a.status')`