# jQuery Class selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I'm struggling to make an alert come up when an anchor tag with a specific class is clicked inside of a div.

My html section in question looks like this...

```
<div id="foo">
  <a class='bar' href='#'>Next</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery section is as follows..

```
$('.bar').click(function()
{
  alert("CLICKED");
});
```

My problem is that I cannot get this alert to come up, I think that I'm properly selecting the class "next", but it won't pick it up for some reason.  I've also tried almost everything on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062989/what-is-the-jquery-selector-for-selecting-anchor-elements-with-a-particular-class) but nothing is working.  If I don't try to specify the anchor tag i.e. $('#foo').click(function()... then it works, but there will be multiple anchor tags within this div, so simply having the alert executed when the div is clicked won't work for what I need.  The website this is on is a search engine using ajax to send information to do_search.php.  Within the do_search.php I make pagination decisions based on how many results are found, and if applicable, a next, previous, last, and first link may be made and echoed.

EDIT: I just figured it out, it was my placement of the .next function, since it wasn't created on the initial document load but instead after a result had been returned, I moved the .next function to the success part of the ajax function since that is where the buttons will be created if they need to be, now it works.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using the `live()` command:

`$(".bar").live("click", function(){ alert(); });`

Because you load your button via AJAX, the click event isn't binded to it. If you use the live() command, it will automatically bind events to all elements created after the page has loaded.

More details, [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: This did it, makes a lot more sense for me to do it like this too.  Thanks for this information, i didn't know about the live() command.

Comment: [`.live` is now deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Instead, use `$(document).on('click','.bar', function() { ... });` -- http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 10):

.live is now deprecated and is the selected answer for this. The answer is in the comments in the selected answer above. Here is the solution that resolved it for me:

```
$(document).on('click','.bar', function() { alert(); });
```

Thanks to @Blazemonger for the fix.

Answer (score 7):

You surely missed `$(document).ready()`. Your code should be:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bar').click(function()
      {
        alert("CLICKED");
      });
    });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Alternatively, moving the code $('.bar').click() after the HTML declarations might work. However the gist of the problem is that you try to assign a listener to a DOMElement that might not have been created. Edgar's comment above fixes that. Cheers

Comment: If $(document).ready... is already present, then ensure that jQuery is actualyl included, and the path is correct.
your code itself works fine, see here - http://jsbin.com/ayiquk/

Comment: I have the jquery library included and $(document).ready, what I showed is a section of my scripts file which i have included with the website.  This is the only part of it that doesn't seem to work.  I think that I should've  provided more information in my original post, this next button is actually created later, the site is a search engine which uses ajax to send information to a do_search php script which queries a mysql db.  This next button is created in the php script and echoed back based on how many pages of information there are.  There is also a previous, last, and first button.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have included `JQuery Library` properly.
2. Make sure your script has written between `$(document).ready() in short $(function(){  });`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/W9PXG/1/

```
<div id="foo">
  <a class='bar' href='#'>Next</a>
</div>

$(function(){
$('a.bar').click(function()
  {
    alert("CLICKED");
});
});
```